# Why different results - same query - different computer

Tags: nmap

I have 3 computers - side by side.  All connected via WIFI to same access point.  `nmap -sP 192.168.1.1/24` used to find active hosts on my local network.  Two see typically 18 hosts while the other may see only 4 or 5.  Another pc wire connected to the same router also sees 18.

Not critical - just a curiosity question.  I have looked at the router display and see no differences in place on any of these.

Comment: Can you show us route tables of all three? Thanks.

Comment: We're trying to learn more about why ARP scan misses hosts in some cases. Can you provide packet captures or other info? http://issues.nmap.org/92

Comment: Asking for route tables was an eye opener.  d1 is the one that was giving strange results.  I have no idea what this is or where it came from.  Keep in mind that this is after a rebot and things seem to be working OK now.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is after a reboot and things seem to be working OK now. 
d1  (bad guy)
default via 192.168.1.254 dev wlp3s0  proto static  metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp3s0  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.1.111 dev wlp3s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.111  metric 600 
192.168.1.254 dev wlp3s0  proto static  scope link  metric 600 
pi-1
ip route
default via 192.168.1.254 dev wlx000b819510cc src 192.168.1.109 metric 303 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlx000b819510cc proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.109 metric 303

Answer (score 1):

When ping scanning directly attached network, nmap sends ARP packets to the subnet. When you give it wrong network address this may fail for some reason and behave erratically.

Try 192.168.1.0/24 instead of 192.168.1.1/24.

192.168.1.0/24 is your correct network address

Also, nmap sends ARP packets only when running as root or administrator. This way it can reliably detect all hosts running on local subnet (directly attached) without connecting to every machine. When running as unprivileged user, it tries to connect to port 80. If these are firewalled, it will not detect any host.

Comment: With $sudo nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24  i get 20, 21 & 7 hosts up on the respective computers.  All this within a minute of each other.

Comment: You might have some network configuration error on that host you get only 7, for example, wrong netmask, or duplicated ip address. Maybe some firewall is blocking something. Hard to think about other options.

Comment: You should also be able to ping all 21 ips with arping, like `arping -I interface 192.168.1.101`. This is how nmap tries to ping every IP on the subnet.

Comment: netmask shows all 255's which is strange.  I gave up and rebooted and counts come out OK.  netmask still shows 255's but all working.  I often don't understand everything I know about this stuff :-(  Thanks for the help!